# Sorting data by date of data using PHP Jquery

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have code as below:

```
 <?php
    $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
    include("lib/db_function.php"); 
    $order = '';
?> 
  <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#sortup').hide();
        $('#sortdown').click(function(e) {
            $('#sortup').show();
            $('#sortdown').hide();              
        <?php
            $order = "ORDER BY datestart ASC";
         ?>

        });

        $('#sortup').click(function(e) {
            $('#sortup').hide();
            $('#sortdown').show();
            <?php
                $order = "ORDER BY dateend ASC";
            ?>

        });
     });
    </script>

   <?php    

            //this point I can not get the `$order` when I click on the button sort

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblproject WHERE prostatus ='show' ".$order."";
    $exc = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
 ?>
```

I'm trying to sort data from database by using this code above,but it not work because it display only this `ORDER BY dateend ASC`. Anyone help me please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can not set php variable using javascript that way. you have to use Ajax. it'll be little bit complicated if I explain all things here, and also there is so many reference already exist on the internet: https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax good luck !